# No EndPoint configured for CLI C++ calling C# dll calling WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, c++-cli

I am building a CLI/C++ dll that will be used as a plugin to an EXE file. The CLI/C++ project has a reference to a C# dll. Further, the C# dll has a Service Reference to a WCF Web Service.

I used to get a runtime exception saying "FileNotFound". I discovered that the C# dll has to be in the same folder as the EXE in order for it to be found. However, now I get an exception that there is no EndPoint configured for the ServiceRefernce.

Has anyone worked with a similar case? Do I need to copy the Service Reference config files to the same folder as the EXE as well?

Answer (score 0):

The service reference configuration needs to be copied to the configuration file of the executable. An application config file for another assembly cannot be (easily) loaded into an executing assembly.